# Finding the next node in a BST

Tags: haskell

Is there a more elegant way to do this? My solution doesn't feel particularly Haskell-y.

I also wrote a version where nodes don't have a parent pointer, but it's a bit less efficient.

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}

module BST (next) where

-- Define BST datatype

data BST a where
  Nil :: BST a
  Node :: (Eq a, Ord a) => (BST a) -> a -> (BST a) -> (BST a) -> (BST a)

instance Eq (BST a) where
  Nil == Nil = True
  Nil == _ = False
  _ == Nil = False
  (Node _ a _ _) == (Node _ b _ _) = a == b

instance (Show a) => Show (BST a) where
  show Nil = ""
  show (Node l v r _) = "(" ++ show v ++ ")"

-- Accessors

left :: BST a -> BST a
left Nil = Nil
left (Node Nil _ _ _) = Nil
left (Node l _ _ _) = l

-- Utility functions
min :: BST a -> BST a
min Nil = Nil
min n@(Node Nil _ _ _) = n
min (Node l _ _ _) = BST.min l

-- Traverse up, until we find a parent node that has a value larger than a.
bigParent :: a -> BST a -> BST a
bigParent _ Nil = Nil
bigParent a p@(Node _ pa _ pp)
  | pa > a = p
  | otherwise = bigParent a pp

-- Next node
next :: BST a -> BST a
next Nil = Nil
next (Node _ _ r@Node{} _) = BST.min r
next n@(Node _ a _ p)
  | n == left p = p
  | otherwise = bigParent a p

-- Tests

--              8
--           /    \
--         3       10
--       /  \       \
--     1     6       14
--         /  \     /
--       4     7  13

n1 = Node Nil 1 Nil n3
n4 = Node Nil 4 Nil n6
n7 = Node Nil 7 Nil n6
n6 = Node n4 6 n7 n3
n3 = Node n1 3 n6 n8
n13 = Node Nil 13 Nil n14
n14 = Node n13 14 Nil n10
n10 = Node Nil 10 n14 n8
n8 = Node n3 8 n10 Nil

main = do
  expect "n1" (next n1) n3
  expect "n3" (next n3) n4
  expect "n4" (next n4) n6
  expect "n6" (next n6) n7
  expect "n7" (next n7) n8
  expect "n8" (next n8) n10
  expect "n10" (next n10) n13
  expect "n13" (next n13) n14

expect :: Eq a => String -> a -> a -> IO ()
expect name actual expected = case actual == expected of
  True -> putStrLn $ "[" ++ name ++ "] OK"
  False -> putStrLn $ "[" ++ name ++ "] FAIL"
```

Comment: Creating a tree with back pointers is easy in the static case, but might be painful when you want to dynamically do so (this is called tying the knot). Since you've specified this tree statically, the test case works, but I think it will be much harder to implement a `mkBST :: Ord a => [a] -> BST a`, compared to a tree without back pointers. Moreover, you cannot have sharing between two trees this way, you will need to duplicate entire trees for the tiniest of modifications.

Comment: Here it is without back pointers. I wish there was a way to generalize it more, though -- it still feels inelegant. https://github.com/bcherny/bst-next/blob/master/src/v2-noparent.hs